# Enabling php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so cause apache to break

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to enable php on my Mac. I am following a tutorial that someone put together that allow me to run multiple websites using httpd-vhosts. That tutorial is here ->https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/#comment-25907.

I actually set this up a year or so ago and everything worked perfectly. I think because of a recent update, it stopped working. I decided to change out the edited files with the original copies and start over. I'm able to go to localhost up to a certain point with it giving me the "It works!" text. However when I uncomment the line "LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so" in my httpd.conf file everything starts messing up. I restart apache and go to localhost and it tells me the server can't be found. I refresh the page and it shows me "It works!". I refresh the page and it tells me the server can't be found. I'm so confused. I don't know if it is because of the php module or what.

Any assistance would be helpful. I can give any more information that I need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the apache error log says? It probably crashes the httpd process, hence the local server becoming unvailable.

You say that you haven't used that for one year. If you upgraded OSX in the meantime, you probably switched from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4. Check that your PHP module matches Apache specs. Using an outdated PHP module with a newer Apache version will cause this kind of behaviour because they are not using the same API.

Alternatively, since you don't seem to be an expert in httpd/PHP stacks (no offense!) you could use a tool like MAMP to make things easier.

If you want to keep your current setup, make sure you upgrade the PHP module as well so it's compatible with your new Apache version.

Comment: haha. no offense taken.  I can't seem to wrap my head around the process. The reason I started using the setup provided in the tutorial because it showed me how to use httpd-vhosts to have multiple websites. (i.e. example1.dev, example2.dev) I know MAMP pro offers that, but I don't want to have to pay for a program that I could do without the program.

How do I update the PHP module? I thought I did but still nothing.

Comment: MAMP offers that too if you edit the config yourself, which you already do anyway ;-) You just don't get any "assistant" with the normal MAMP.

Comment: So I can download the free MAMP, edit the config file, and have the ability to have multiple websites?

Comment: Yes, exactly like you would do with a "vanilla" Apache/PHP stack, except it's sandboxed and the initial setup is way easier. All the Apache config files are structured in the exact same way and are located in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache`. Uncomment the `#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` line and then edit the vhosts config file to setup your virtual hosts like you were doing before